# Checking if string contains only allowed characters

Tags: java, android, string, matcher

I want to check if my string contains only allowed character. Matcher works properly, but when I input something like this "123A" app crashes. For only letters it work properly(error). How can I do that?

My code:

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
matcher = pattern.matcher(stNumber);
  if(matcher.find())
else
   error
```

This is my logcat error:

```
03-07 21:49:50.917    1891-1891/com.converter_numeralsystem.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.converter_numeralsystem.app, PID: 1891
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "112a"
        at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
        at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:361)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:352)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:318)
        at com.converter_numeralsystem.app.MainActivity.calculate(MainActivity.java:121)
        at com.converter_numeralsystem.app.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:246)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's your logcat error?

Comment: Please post your log cat error

Comment: Now it is in question.

Comment: So in the end you want to validate that your String has only numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow only numbers, you should use a regular expression to match the whole string (add `+` to check for at least one digit). Also, use `matches()` method instead of `find()` to match the whole input string (your problem is that `find()` finds the first match and then doesn't try to match the rest):

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
matcher = pattern.matcher(stNumber);
  if(matcher.matches())
else
   error
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
```

Or

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
```

Also use

```
if(matcher.match())
```

Instead of

```
if(matcher.find())
```

Comment: The problem is with using `find()` so tha won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an edit text for which you want to introduce only numbers you could add this attribute to your edit text in your xml file:

```
android:digits="0123456789"
```